# Find a Path through an physical maze in C

Tags: c, arrays, maze

So we have one Robot that drives through a maze (nothing I need to worry about), writes down detected walls and ways and sends it to another robot, which shall drive straight through the maze to reach the exit.
I have already written a zigbee program to send the maze (2 dimensional array) and i guess it should work (could not test it yet since i have only one robot at home).
So My Robot gets the 2 dimensional array.
For Example:

**1** 0 0 **1 1 1 1 1 1 1**
**1** 0 0 **1 1 1 1 1 1 1**
**1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**
**1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**
**1 1 1 1 1 1 1** 0 0 **1**
**1** 0 0 **1** 0 0 **1** 0 0 **1**
**1** 0 0 **1** 0 0 **1** 0 0 **1**
**1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**
**1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**
**1 1 1 1 1 1 1** 0 0 **1**

<1> symbols a wall and <0> symbols the way (it has to be 2 next to each other, since one number is equal to 10cm / 3,9 inches).
And now I really have no idea how to get my robot to drive the right path.

Comment: You want a pathing algorithm - Dijkstra’s algorithm, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the maze has no cycles, then all of its walls form two parallel (though contorted) lines between the entrance and the exit. Just follow one of them consistent (e.g. always take the right, and walk along the edge of the free space). This is not the optimal path, for sure - but it's pretty simple to implement.

If there *are* cycles you won't have it *that* easy. You can read up on some [maze-solving algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) on Wikipedia. One option which @nneoneo suggests is using Dijkstra's algorithm, with the "graph" having all n^2 maze squares as nodes, and edges between two adjacent empty (`0`) nodes. It's a bit memory-heavy, but its performance is not so bad and it's not very complicated.

More interesting reading: Look up the Greek myth of Theseus in the Labyrinth. He used a ball of yarn to track his path.

Comment: Yeah thats how the first robot drives through it (staying on the left wall). But my Robot (the second one) shall calculate the right path before starting to drive.

Comment: @Schurke: What does your robot know, at any given time? If it has the full map of the maze, then it doesn't need to "start driving" - it can pretend to start driving, use the "left wall" approach, figure out the full correct path, and then take it.

Comment: it knows the whole maze the first robot drove. But I still dont get how to write a function for that. For example: if(Maze[9][9] && [9][8] == 0) but what then? I really have no clue

Comment: "Starting to drive" means printing the driving instructions or sending them somewhere, right? Well, don't do that. Have your program run the same as for the first robot, but keep the instructions to yourself. Only when you've found a path - issue them.

Comment: "Starting to drive" means literally starting to drive. It is a robot with 4 Wheels which gets like a map of the maze via xbee. I can't do the same I did with the first robot, since the first robot just checks if it is physically at a wall (distance sensors) and if not, it turns left. But the second robot needs to know which is the correct path from the beginning so it does not turn into a dead end.